# Lighttpd WARNING: unknown config-key: proxy.forwarded (ignored) and proxy.header

Tags: lighttpd

I have a flask application on port 5000 and I set up a reverse proxy using lighttpd. I want to get the client IP accessing my server but I encountered an error that proxy.forwarded and proxy.header is an unknown key but proxy.server is working. I already enabled mod_proxy on my configuration. Here is my config

```
  server.modules = (
        "mod_access",
        "mod_accesslog",
        "mod_alias",
        "mod_compress",
        "mod_redirect",
        "mod_proxy"
    )
    
    $SERVER["socket"] == ":80" {
      $HTTP["url"] =~ "^/" {
        proxy.server = ( "/" => (( "host" => "0.0.0.0", "port" => 5000)))
        proxy.forwarded = ("for"  => 1, "proto" => 1)
        proxy.header = ("upgrade"  => "enable")
      }
    }
```

Or is there another way to achieve getting the client IP?

My lighttpd version is lighttpd/1.4.45
My OS Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 1):

Your version of lighttpd is too old: support for [proxy.forwarded](https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/Docs_ModProxy) was implemented in 1.4.51, according to the documentation.